# Как задать описание бота Telegram

Tags: telegram-bot

Подскажите, знающие люди, как сделать такое сообщение до отправки команды /start?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам требуется обратиться к [@BotFather](https://t.me/BotFather) (бот, который регистрирует новых ботов) и дать ему [команду](https://core.telegram.org/bots#botfather-commands) `/setdescription`. "Description" бота - это в точности текст, который виден всем пользователям перед началом беседы.